# Ignore NaN values when searching for a minimum datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following piece of code:

```
if isinstance(df["col1"][0], datetime.datetime):
   min_dt = min(df["col1"].values)
```

It searches for a minimum date value in a column `col1`. However, it checks the data type of the first rows, while there might be empty values in the rest of rows. How can I ignore empty values when searching for a minimum date value in a column?

Now I get this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

Comment: have you tried convert `col1` using pd.to_datetime() and after use the suggestion of Mstaino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the builtin DataFrame `min` method you can automatically ignore NaNs (there's even a `skipna` argument just for that). Much better than python `min`

```
min_dt = df["col1"].min()
```

EDIT:

If you have some dates in string format, try converting them first :

```
min_dt = df['col1'].apply(pd.to_datetime).min()
```

Comment: I still get the same error message at the line `min_dt = df["col1"].min()`. Do you know why it may happen?

Comment: most likely your first row is `datetime.datetime` and other rows are string, try what Terry mentioned